# Detect if user has already liked a FB page without user_likes permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to know if the user has already liked my FB page in order to show him the button widget or not.

I was using `user_likes` permission to do this (Rails - Koala):

```
@alreadyLiked = @api.get_object("me/likes/123412341234")
```

But I got feedback from Facebook that I must not use that user_likes permission to do this. Is there a way to do this without that permission? For instance, to know whether the button widget is showing the "You like this" or the "Like" text?

**EDIT:** this is not a page tab, but an Android app using Graph API

Comment: If it is not a pagetab app you can not do that

Comment: Facebook allows "incentivize a like to your app's page" not only for pagetab apps, but for any kind of Facebook app. There is now workaround to know if a user has already liked my page?

Comment: No there is no workaround

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to achieve this on a Facebook Page, you should use the `signed_request` returned by the Page that is POSTed to your app on first load. It will include information about the user, including whether they've liked the page, is an admin and a user_id if they're authenticated.

If you decode the signed_request, you will see something like:

```
{
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [issued_at] => 1378146888
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1234567890
            [liked] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => gb
            [locale] => en_US
            [age] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )

        )

}
```

You can check if `page['liked'] == 1` to check if the user has liked the page.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a "page tab" app. Just an Android app that uses Facebook Graph API. So a Facebook user can like from it my page. I suppose the above cannot work for my app.